# Publish database function of visual studio in Rider

Tags: visual-studio, database-project, rider

I recently moved from visual studio to Rider and I love it. However I've noticed that Rider does not have a function to publish your database project to a server. Does Rider have this option or anything like it? If not what would be the best alternative? I'd rather not have both IDEs open at the same time just for 1 function.

Comment: How did you solve the problem? I'd like to switch myself and my colleagues from VS to Rider, but many of them would miss features of integrated DB project too much. And paying for both is not an option - Rider isn't that much better.

Answer (score 0):

Database projects (*.sqlproj) in Visual Studio allow you to publish a database, which is useful.

Rider [doesn't support this type of project](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/compare/rider-vs-visual-studio/) at the moment:

[image]

However, there are some alternatives. For example, Rider has supported [EF code-first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/ef6/modeling/index) since [2018](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/04/06/entity-framework-support-rider-2018-1/), so that would be one way of managing your database. EF lets your code generate and update a database, via [migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli). Or even via SQL scripts which it generates.

Another example, would be to [generate and publish scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/generate-and-publish-scripts-wizard?source=recommendations&view=sql-server-ver16) via [SQL Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16). The scripts could be added to your project/source-control as SQL files.